# I m not be able to get correct number of order_status

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join, count

I m trying to get count of order_registration.status using like in join table

```
SELECT dstr_operator_master.*, 
count(order_registration.status like'%enquiry%') AS order_status, 
count(order_registration.pname) AS destiList 
FROM dstr_operator_master 
left JOIN order_registration 
ON FIND_IN_SET( order_registration.user_id , dstr_operator_master.u_id) 
WHERE dstr_operator_master.status = '1' 
and dstr_operator_master.type ='distributor' 
GROUP BY dstr_operator_master.auto_id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT d.*, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN o.status LIKE '%enquiry%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS order_status, 
       COUNT(o.pname) AS destiList 
FROM   dstr_operator_master d
LEFT JOIN order_registration o ON FIND_IN_SET(o.user_id, d.u_id) 
WHERE d.status = '1' AND d.type = 'distributor' 
GROUP BY d.auto_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your counts are probably going to be returning the same values, because `COUNT()` counts the number of non-`NULL` values.  For the first one, use `SUM()` instead of `COUNT()`:

```
SELECT dstr_operator_master.*, 
       SUM(order_registration.status LIKE'%enquiry%') AS order_status, 
       Count(order_registration.pname)                AS destiList 
. . .
```

MySQL treats booleans as numbers in a numeric context, with true being 1 and false being 0.  This is why the `SUM()` works.